# Deadlock error messages in crawl server and search not working in SharePoint web application

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, crawling, index, deadlock

In SharePoint 2010 Search Service Application when i remove content source and run again full crawl on same content source

I found below errors and users unable to search documents

> A database error occurred. Source: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0 Code: 1205 occurred 1 time(s) Description: Transaction (Process ID 329) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has
>   been chosen as the deadlock
>
> CGatherer::LoadTransactionsFromCrawlInternal fails Error 0x80004005,
>   CrawlID 1741342  [gatherobj.cxx:4663] 
>   d:\office\source\search\native\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx
>
> SQL call failed (0x80004005: Unspecified error  )
>   [atldbext.cxx:1290]  d:\office\source\search\libs\utild\atldbext.cxx
>
> A database error occurred. Source: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0 Code: 1205 occurred 1 time(s) Description: Transaction (Process ID 329) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has
>   been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.  Context:
>   Application ''
>
> error 0: Transaction (Process ID 329) was deadlocked on lock resources
>   with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun
>   the transaction. (source Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0,
>   0x80004005, code 1205: Unspecified error  )  [atldbext.cxx:1386] 
>   d:\office\source\search\libs\utild\atldbext.cxxa

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Search Service having issues.
I would start with restarting the Servers.

Microsoft offered a few solutions:

- Verify you can connect to SQL (i.e. TCP/IP is enabled in the SQL
  configuration manager, firewall ports are open, SQL credentials are
  correct)
- Disable TCP Chimney Offloading (see
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037) on your SharePoint and SQL
  machine.

I would also try to clear the Config Cache.

If nothing works then recommend apporach is

- Delete the Search Server Application
- Verify that your Search Server databases were also deleted
- Restart the SharePoint machine (not just the app, but the entire
  machine instance)
- Finally, recreate a Search Server Application

Reference: http://jdav.is/2012/11/08/issues-with-sharepoint-search/